# Problema ao pegar dados por ID na API com Slim

Tags: php, slim

Estou tentando criar uma API com o Slim para poder alimentar um app, mas me deparei com o seguinte problema: Eu consigo pegar todos os dados do db, mas não consigo pegar um dado específico.

Na url: `http://localhost/api/` que é onde pego todos os dados, eu consigo retornar um json com todos os dados cadastrados, tudo certinho. Mas se eu tentar com `http://localhost/api/people/3` ele me retorna um json vazio.

Esse é o código que estou usando:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'lib/mysql.php';
use \Slim\App;

$app = new App();

$app->get('/', 'get_peoples');

$app->get('/people/{id}', function($request, $response, $args) {
    get_people_id($args['id']);
});

$app->run();

function get_peoples() {
    $db  = connect_db();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM peoples ORDER BY 'name'";
    $exe = $db->query($sql);
    $data = $exe->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $db = null;
    echo json_encode($data);
}

function get_people_id($people_id) {
    $db = connect_db();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM peoples WHERE 'id' = '$people_id'";
    $exe = $db->query($sql);
    $data = $exe->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $db = null;
    echo json_encode($data);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na função get_people_id, basta remover as aspas da coluna id. Tipo assim:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM peoples WHERE id = '$people_id'";
```

Como chega a ser retornado um JSON vazio significa que a sintaxe da passagem de parâmetros pela URL está correta, restando como causa de erro a consulta SQL.

Comment: Valeu, o problema era as aspas mesmo rsrs.